Create a relative and fixed time frame query visual in Datadog
I have a RUM query visual in Datadog that counts the number of views. Instead of using the dashboard's timeframe, I want to count the views from a fixed timeframe one week back from the current day. For example, if today is Monday, I want to see the view count from 09:00 to 12:00 last Monday. This time period (09:00 - 12:00) remains fixed as long as I am viewing the query on Monday. On Tuesday, the visual should shift to show data from 09:00 - 12:00 on the previous Tuesday, and so on. Is this possible?
